# simple CUDA program execution without GPU hardware using NVIDIA GPU computing SDK 4.0 and microsoft VC++ 2010 express

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I am new to GPU computing , but somewhere I've read that it's possible to execute a CUDA program without a GPU card using a simulator/ emulator. I have installed NVIDIA's GPU Computing SDK 4.0 and Visual C++ 2010 Express on Windows Vista. I would like to know:

- Whether it is feasible or not to run CUDA code without a GPU, using NVIDA's Computing SDK 4.0 and Visual C++ 2010 express?
- Why I get the following error, when I try to execute a sample program I have:

  ```
  ------ Build started: Project: example1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ 
  1>  '"\nvcc.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
  1>  operable program or batch file. 
  1>  Performing Custom Build Tools 
  1> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5):
  error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.
  ```

I'm unsure if I have installed all the required software, if something else is needed, or if I need to use another version of the product.

Comment: CUDA requires the full version of visual studio, it does not work with visual studio express.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the NVIDA CUDA Toolkit 4.0 witch brings you the nvcc compiler, all headers and libraries needet to build a CUDA program.

The CUDA Toolkit can be found here [CUDA Toolkit 4.0](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-40)

As far as i know the emulation mode is no longer supported in CUDA versions >= 3.0, if i'm wrong someone may correct me on this topic. You'll need a CUDA enabled device to run a CUDA program.

Comment: Indeed, newer versions of CUDA Toolkit don't support EMULATOR anymore.  So I suggest you [stay with an older version](http://if.us.edu.pl/~dawid/CUDA/cudemul.html), like CUDA Toolkit 2.3.

Comment: The older versions of the SDK had less VS integration and the emulator was very slow. I'd really recommend ponying up the $ for a CUDA capable card. Unless you want something cutting edge we're not talking a lot of money here.