# CUDA code without a GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, pycuda

I have a 13.02 Ubuntu desktop OS. I am a newbie in CUDA and have been given a task to write CUDA code without NIVDIA graphics card.

Due to lack of my knowledge - that /dev/nivdia card & driver should be required for CUDA programming I wasted a week for its installation. Now that I have realized the fact please let me know the best option of developing PyCuda / Cuda apps without using Nvidia GPU.

Also is there any Emulator option to run the code? In all if I do not have a NIVIDA GPU - how I can still make use of my Ubuntu desktop to develop / run / emulate code using CUDA both in Python and C/C++.

It would really help me out if I can get this information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8413836/3651800  Looks like emulation is no longer supported according to this? In any case trying to write parallelized code and emulating sounds painful!

Comment: There are quite a few questions and answers already on the CUDA tag about how to set up systems without a GPU, what you can and can't do without a GPU, and various emulator options.  Have you tried to search for any?  Your questions suggest you have done no research.

Comment: I am but had a terrible experience after my attempts to install CUDA failed. My OS started reporting crash and have to do re-installation completely. Lost all my data - hence trying to be on safe side seeking the best alternative before doing anything on my OS